# How to align a Button to the Right?

Tags: html, css

Good Afternoon,
I realize this topic has been asked several times and has got several solutions to as I have seen from searching your forums.

But solutions such as,
`<input type="button" value="Click Me" **style="float: right;"**>`,

Even though do successfully align the button to the right, they overlap my footer as the button is supposed to be right above the footer. This is my code:

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0FA0FF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.containers-fluid {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"><span>Proceed to Next Lesson </span>
</button>

<footer class="containers-fluid text-center">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add style `float:right` to your `button`

add this between `button` and `footer`

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and css for `clearfix`

```
.clearfix{
 clear: both;
}
```

Read more about [clearfix](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0FA0FF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.containers-fluid {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}
.clearfix{
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"><span>Proceed to Next Lesson </span>
</button>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<footer class="containers-fluid text-center">
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks It work now I will be using this very often in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:right` and set the `position` attribute to `relative`

Comment: Sorry, still the same result.

Comment: To be clear, in CSS, in the .button I added position: relative; and float: right;.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them both inside a container with `display:flex;flex-direction:row;` and then apply `margin-right:0;` to the button.

See the code below

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0FA0FF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px 0 5px auto;
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.containers-fluid {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<button class="button"><span>Proceed to Next Lesson </span>
</button>

<footer class="containers-fluid text-center">
</footer>
</div>
```